# Getting an IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

I'm not sure why I'm getting an

> IndexError: string index out of range

with this code.

```
s = 'oobbobobo'
a = 0
for b in range(len(s)-1):
    if (s[b] == 'b') and (s[b+1] == 'o') and (s[b+2] == s[b]):
        a += 1
    elif (s[b] == 'b') and (s[b+1] == 'o') and None:
        break 

print("Number of times bob occurs is: ", a)
```

I thought the `elif` statement would fix the error, so I'm lost.

Comment: your `for` loop termination condition is wrong, it should be: `for b in range(len(s)-3):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the length of `s` is 9 which means that you're looping over `range(8)` and therefore the highest value that `b` will have is `7` (Stay with me, I'm going somewhere with this ...)

When `b = 7` (on the last iteration of the loop), the conditional expression in the `if` statement is being checked which contains:

```
(s[b+2] == s[b])
```

Well, since `b = 7`, `b + 2 = 9`, but `s[9]` will be out of bounds (remember, python is 0 indexed so the highest index in a a string of length `9` is `8`).

I'm guessing that the fix is to just modify the `range` statement:

```
for b in range(len(s)-2):
    ...
```